# compiler adding references operator

Tags: c++, reference

I  try to call a class function  from another class an I get something absolutely weird

all parameters are treated as references , and i cant see why the compiler threat this as a special case

```
class AbstractModulation 
{
public: 

    virtual bool isValidMatch(
            FOLTerm* toMatch,
            std::set<FOLVariable>* toMatchVariables, 
            FOLTerm* possibleMatch,
            unordered_map<FOLVariable, FOLTerm*>* substitution)=0;
...
```

this line:

```
abstractModulation->isValidMatch(toMatch, toMatchVariables,(FOLTerm*) variable,substitution)
```

causes this error (see the & character added to each parameter..wtf?):

```
AbstractModulation.cpp:105:104: error: no matching function for call to ‘AbstractModulation::isValidMatch(FOLTerm*&, std::vector<FOLVariable>*&, FOLTerm*, std::unordered_map<FOLVariable, FOLTerm*>*&)’
```

candidate:

```
AbstractModulation.h:44:7: note: bool AbstractModulation::isValidMatch(FOLTerm*, std::set<FOLVariable>*, FOLTerm*, std::unordered_map<FOLVariable, FOLTerm*>*)
```

and here are the objjects pointers from the calling class

```
class IdentifyCandidateMatchingTerm : public FOLVisitor 
{
private:
    FOLTerm* toMatch;
    vector<FOLVariable>* toMatchVariables;
    FOLTerm* matchingTerm;
    unordered_map<FOLVariable, FOLTerm*>* substitution;
```

please help me out, this is really weird...

Comment: That is a lot of pointers. I doubt you really need pointers for all of these, or at least use smart pointers.

Comment: 'I' should be capitalized whether it's the start or middle of a sentence.  As a minimum, please remember that rule.

Comment: come on...     ok i changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your function taking `std::set<FOLVariable>*` variable but you try to call it with `std::vector<FOLVariable>*`.

```
error: no matching function for call to 
        ‘AbstractModulation::isValidMatch(FOLTerm*&, std::vector<FOLVariable>*&,
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But definition is

```
virtual bool isValidMatch( FOLTerm* toMatch, std::set<FOLVariable>*
                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

This clearly explains what is going on. Double check how and where you are calling this method.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, stupid of me, thx for pointing this out, i been digging for 1/2 h lol